# Unable to execute Meta filters in JBehave

Tags: jbehave

Some how my JUnitRunner is unable to pick the Scenarios with the meta tag specified in JBehave.

Following is my story:

```
Meta:
**@TestType Smoke**
Scenario: Verify Successful login flow
Given Init my scenario for <ScenarioName>
Given I successfully launch the application
When user enters <validusername> and <validpassword> and click on Login button
Then user is navigated to Home page
Then verify entered username should be displayed
Then I logout from the application
Then Complete Tear Down

Examples:
|ScenarioName|validusername|validpassword|
|Successful Login to Chiron|abcde|12345|


Scenario: Verify Failed login flow
Given Init my scenario for <ScenarioName>
Given I successfully launch the application
When user enters <invalidusername> and <invalidpassword> and click on Login button
Then user should be in Login page itself
Then Complete Tear Down

Examples:
|ScenarioName|invalidusername|invalidpassword|
|Verify Failed login|abcdefg|ijklmn|
```

Following is my runner file:

```java
public class JUnitRunnerWithTags extends JUnitStoryMaps {

    public JUnitRunnerWithTags() {
        configuredEmbedder().useMetaFilters(metaFilters());
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
            .useStoryReporterBuilder(new StoryReporterBuilder()
                .withCodeLocation(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass())));
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> metaFilters() {
        return Arrays.asList("**+TestType Smoke**");
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> storyPaths() {
        return new StoryFinder().findPaths(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()), "**/LoginToApplication.story", "");

    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(),
                new HomePageSteps(),
                new DashboardSteps()
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void run() throws Throwable {
        super.run();
    }

}
```

When i run the above class as JUnit test, the actual tests with the Smoke tag is not getting invoked and nothing is getting executed.

Following is what i am getting when i execute above code

```
Using controls EmbedderControls[batch=false,skip=false,generateViewAfterStories=true,ignoreFailureInStories=false,ignoreFailureInView=false,verboseFailures=false,verboseFiltering=false,storyTimeouts=300,threads=1,failOnStoryTimeout=false]
Processing system properties {}
Mapping story stories/functionaltest/login/LoginToApplication.story with meta filters [+TestType Smoke]
Generating maps view to 'D:\Cigniti\Work\Projects\automation\target\jbehave' using story maps 'StoryMaps[metaFilters=[, +TestType Smoke]]' and view properties '{navigator=ftl/jbehave-navigator.ftl, views=ftl/jbehave-views.ftl, reports=ftl/jbehave-reports.ftl, nonDecorated=ftl/jbehave-report-non-decorated.ftl, decorated=ftl/jbehave-report-decorated.ftl, maps=ftl/jbehave-maps.ftl}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should extend `JUnitStories` (not `JUnitStoryMaps`) to run stories:

```java
public class JUnitRunnerWithTags extends JUnitStories {

    public JUnitRunnerWithTags() {
        configuredEmbedder().useMetaFilters(Arrays.asList("**+TestType Smoke**"));
    }

...
```

More details on:

- [Story Mapping](http://jbehave.org/reference/latest/story-mapping.html)
- [JUnit-enabled Embeddables](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/developing-stories.html)

Comment: As specified in the link also observe they have extended "JUnitStoryMaps" if we need to deal with Meta tags in your suite.

Comment: @Uday the second link also contains commented example of meta filters `configuredEmbedder().useMetaFilters(Arrays.asList("+theme parametrisation"));`

Comment: Thanks VaL, as i shown in my post, i already have 
 in my code. configuredEmbedder().useMetaFilters(metaFilters());  @Override
    protected List<String> metaFilters() {
        return Arrays.asList("**+TestType Smoke**");
    }

Comment: Nope....I dont hear any other solutions yet. Whatever you gave to me is already there in the code which i tried.

Comment: Have you replaced `JUnitStoryMaps` to `JUnitStories`?

Comment: Hi Val, i am overlooked and i thought i apply this Meta tag for all scenarios in a story. Is there a way that i can apply Meta tag at scenario level. As you specified i updated to JUnitStories and Meta tag is applying at story level.

Comment: @Uday, filters applied at both levels and even more: http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/meta-filtering.html